# How to share/export a global variable between two different perl scripts?

Tags: perl, variables, export, global

How do we share or export a global variable between two different perl scripts.

Here is the situation:

**first.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
our (@a, @b);
.........
```

**second.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
require first.pl;
```

I want to use global variable (`@a`, `@b`) declared in **first.pl**

Also,suppose there's a variable in second perl file same as first perl file. But I want to use first file's variable. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 34):

In general, when you are working with multiple files, and importing variables or subroutines between them, you will find that requiring files ends up getting a bit complicated as your project grows.  This is due to everything sharing a common namespace, but with some variables declared in some files but not others.

The usual way this is resolved in Perl is to create modules, and then import from those modules.  In this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package My::Module;  # saved as My/Module.pm
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter;
our @ISA = 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(@a @b);

our (@a, @b);

@a = 1..3;
@b = "a".."c";
```

and then to use the module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Module;  # imports / declares the two variables

print @a;
print @b;
```

That `use` line actually means:

```
BEGIN {
    require "My/Module.pm";
    My::Module->import();
}
```

The `import` method comes from `Exporter`.  When it is called, it will export the variables in the `@EXPORT` array into the calling code.

Looking at the documentation for [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Exporter) and [perlmod](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlmod) should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 19):

They will share global variables, yes.  Are you seeing some problem with that?

Example:

first.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

our (@a, @b);

@a = 1..3;
@b = "a".."c";
```

second.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

require "first.pl";

our (@a,@b);
print @a;
print @b;
```

Giving:

```
$ perl second.pl
123abc
```

Comment: Thanks.... i missed to declare same variable in the second.pl.   Initially, when it was not declared,it says, Variable "@a" is not imported at ..... It is working now...

Answer (score 2):

Cant you use package and export the variable?

Comment: Thanks.... After this problem.... i am exploring the use of package.    Thanks anyway.