# How to share a global parameter across 2 different perl scripts

Tags: perl, export, global-variables

There is a same question on the forum. 
[How to share/export a global variable between two different perl scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543934/how-to-share-export-a-global-variable-between-two-different-perl-scripts)

But, the suggestion for that was to use 'our' while declaration and then add 'require' in the other script. When I tried using it, the script fails saying 'Use of reserved word "our" is deprecated'.

Is there a different way to share parameter across different files. Thanks.

Comment: You must have a really old perl version, what is it? `perl -v`

Comment: Perl version 5.005_03

Comment: That is 15 years old!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the `our` keyword, then you have to fall back to simply using the variable without declaring it properly:

```
{
  no strict;
  $variable = "foo"; # implicitly a global
}
```

The syntax

```
$MyPackage::variable = "foo"; # uses the fully qualified name
```

should work too.

These will allow you to use the global, but will not scope the visibility of the name correctly.

However, you should absolutely and immediately upgrade that perl — it is a development release and not a regular release. The current release is perl5 v16.2.