# How to print the elements of a hash that is defined in another file?

Tags: perl, hash, require

How to print the elements of a hash that is defined in another file?

file1.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
our %hash = 
("Quarter" , 25,
 "Dime"    , 10,
 "Nickel"  , 5 );
```

file2.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
require "file1.pl"
foreach (sort keys %hash){
print "$hash{$_}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name.
Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name.
```

---

Kindly help

Comment: For future reference, select your code, then press Ctrl-K or the appropriate button in the toolbar to make your code look right.

Comment: (Ignore my vote to close. The post I mentioned in the close vote has inserted a bug in their answer since yesterday.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543934/how-to-share-export-a-global-variable-between-two-different-perl-scripts this question looks similar to what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules need a `package` statement and must end with a true value. (It currently returns a true value, but I like to use an explicit `1;`.) It's better to give them the `.pm` extension.

```
# MyConfig.pm
package MyConfig;
use strict;
use warnings;
our %hash = (
   "Quarter" => 25,
   "Dime"    => 10,
   "Nickel"  =>  5,
);
1;
```

Now, if you left it at that, you'd need to use `%MyConfig::hash` instead of `%hash`. So we need to export the var from the module to the user's namespace.

```
# MyConfig.pm
package MyConfig;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( %hash );
our %hash = (
   "Quarter" => 25,
   "Dime"    => 10,
   "Nickel"  =>  5,
);
1;
```

So on to the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyConfig;
for (sort keys %hash) {
   print "$hash{$_}\n";
}
```

`use MyConfig;` does a require (if necessary) and an import. The latter brings the variables and subs listed in `@EXPORT` into the current namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That will be of great help!

Comment: The reason you want to use a proper module is so can do `use MyConfig;` from multiple places in your application without problem. It might not be needed in this particular project, but doing `do 'helper.pl' or die $@;` is a bad habit to get into even if it's a couple of lines shorter. TLP's suggestion to use an actual config file format for a config file is a very good idea, though.

Comment: I get your point. I got one more doubt. Now If I have to declare a package, Is it necessary that the file be a .pm file? Or any other file format would do?

Comment: @VinodRM File format? Did you mean "File extension"? Yes, it does matter if you use the `use` keyword.

Comment: Well, if you changed the extension (e.g. to `.pl`), you'd have to change `use MyConfig;` to `BEGIN { require "MyConfig.pl"; import MyConfig; }`

Comment: @ikegami

Now, in case my hash is a "hash of hashes", how do i print them?

Comment: Nested structure, so nested loops. Outer loop iterates over elements of outer hash. Inner loop over the elements of the inner hash.

Comment: @ikegami
Could you please quote the same with a small example?

Comment: If you don't know how to iterate over the elements of hash, and you can't look it up, you have some learning to do.

Comment: @ikegami 
I know how to iterate through a hash oh hashes(i.e for a hash defined in the same file). But I am not able to understand how to access the hash from another file and iterate through it and print. Kindly help

Comment: You say you know how to visit a HoH, and I already showed how to export a variable, so what's the problem? I don't know what you want from me.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that the code you posted was many edits away from actually giving the error messages you claimed, your problem is that you do not declare `%hash` in file2.pl. Since that file uses the `strict` pragma (which is a good thing), it gives this fatal error. To overcome this, declare the hash:

```
our %hash;
require 'file1.pl';
#... etc.
```

However, if you are trying to use `require` as a means of loading a configuration file, there are many better ways. For example [`Config::Any`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aAny).

Comment: @TLP

If I declare a hash in file2.pl

say, our %hash;

how does it get access to the hash defined in file1.pl?

Comment: @VinodRM They both refer to the same variable, `%main::hash`. If you declared a package, e.g. `package MyConfig` like in ikegami's answer, you could use `%MyConfig::hash` in file1.pl. Which is the explicit package name that the original error message mentioned.