# Export HASH from module

Tags: perl, hash

Can some explain how to pass a HASH from a module to main. I've read posts like [How to share/export a global variable between two different perl scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543934/how-to-share-export-a-global-variable-between-two-different-perl-scripts) and understand the basic concept behind it but this is a little different and I can't find any examples.

This module works if called from main, but how do I just pass the hash to main so that I can print in there, instead of printing it from the module. Or so I can write the key values to file or something.

```
package My::Module;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter;
our @ISA = 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(get_proc_info);

sub get_proc_info
    {

        my %processor;
        Win32::SystemInfo::ProcessorInfo(%processor);
                for (my $i=0;$i<$processor{NumProcessors};$i++)
                {
                    print "Processor $i\n";
                    print "Processor Name: " . $processor{"Processor$i"}{ProcessorName} . "\n";
                    print "Processor Info: " . $processor{"Processor$i"}{Identifier} . "\n";
                    print "Processor Speed: " . $processor{"Processor$i"}{MHZ} . "MHz\n\n"; 
                }  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a reference to it.

The module:

```
package My::Module;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter          qw( import );
use Win32::SystemInfo qw( );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( get_processors );

sub get_processors {
    my %processors;
    Win32::SystemInfo::ProcessorInfo(%processors);
    return \%processors;
}

1;
```

The caller:

```
use My::Module qw( get_processors );

my $processors = get_processors();

for my $i (0 .. $processors->{NumProcessors}-1)
    my $processor = $processors->{"Processor$i"};

    print "Processor $i\n";
    print "Processor Name:  $processor->{ProcessorName}\n";
    print "Processor Info:  $processor->{Identifier}\n";
    print "Processor Speed: $processor->{MHZ} MHz\n"; 
    print "\n";
}
```

---

The above already "fixes" some of `Win32::SystemInfo::ProcessorInfo`'s weird interfaces. The following fixes it further:

The module:

```
package My::Module;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter          qw( import );
use Win32::SystemInfo qw( );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( get_processors );

sub get_processors {
    my %processors;
    Win32::SystemInfo::ProcessorInfo(%processors);
    return
        map { $processors{"Processor$_"} }
            0 .. $processors{NumProcessors}-1;
}

1;
```

The caller:

```
use My::Module qw( get_processors );

my @processors = get_processors();

for my $i (0..$#processors)
    my $processor = $processors[$i];

    print "Processor $i\n";
    print "Processor Name:  $processor->{ProcessorName}\n";
    print "Processor Info:  $processor->{Identifier}\n";
    print "Processor Speed: $processor->{MHZ} MHz\n"; 
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to add a my @processors outside the for loop. Works well! Still trying to wrap my head around this concept of % to @ to $

Comment: hum... `my @processors` should not appear in the first version, and it already appears in the second version.

Comment: Sorry meant, my $processor

Comment: But that's not true. There's a bug if you need `$processor` (singular) outside the loop

Comment: Disregard that, I was being daft. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Exporting variables is a bad practice. You can always export a sub that returns the content of the variable, though:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package HashExport;
    my %hash = ( key => 'value' );

    sub get_hash {
        return %hash
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;
my %imported = HashExport::get_hash();
print Dumper \%imported;
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to do

You can use `Exporter` to export any package identifier. It just happens to be named subroutines that don't need a leading sigil and are always package identifiers

I can create a globally-accessible hash like this

#### MyStuff.pm

```
package MyStuff;

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT_OK = qw/ %Data /;

our %Data = (
    a => 1,
    b => 2,
    c => 3,
);

1;
```

And import and use it like this

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use MyStuff '%Data';

use Data::Dump;

dd \%Data;
```

#### output

```
{ a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 }
```

However *any* sort of global mutable value lays you open to all sorts of *action at a distance* bugs. The alternative of writing a global subroutine that returns a reference to a value is really no better at all